# Windows Terminal: Open cmd.exe then run script

Tags: windows, terminal, batch-file, windows-terminal

I want to create .bat file to open cmd.exe in Windows Terminal and activate python environment

```
cd D:\pythonApp
venv\Scripts\activate
```

this successfully open cmd in Terminal and set the directory

```
wt.exe -d "D:\pythonApp" cmd
```

but I it failed to run `venv\Scripts\activate`

```
wt.exe -d "D:\pythonApp" cmd; venv\Scripts\activate
```

it open 2 tab with error: Termination behavior can be configured at advance profile settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments?tabs=windows#command-line-syntax)

```
wt [options] [command ; ]
```

but the problem there are no mention we should place the `command inside quote`,  so the solution for my problem is `"cmd /k venv\Scripts\activate"`

CMD

```
wt -d "D:\pythonApp" "cmd /k venv\Scripts\activate"
```

PowerShell

```
wt -d "D:\pythonApp" -p "Windows PowerShell" "powershell -NoExit  venv\Scripts\activate"
```